# How do I display my own tweets using new OAuth?

Tags: php, oauth, twitter

I had a twitter timeline displayed on my site using basic authorization. Now it stopped working. I need to make it work again. What should I do?

I've gone through some tutorials and they all were like "how to display timeline from USER THAT ACCESSED YOUR WEB" or "let people tweet from you app", but none of them shows simple scenario like "showing my user timeline on my webpage".

Do I need to register an application on twitter.com for such a simple task? Using basic auth it was simple, *just give me username and proper password and read this json* :)

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this tutorial: [OAuth for PHP Twitter Apps](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/oauth-for-php-twitter-apps-part-1). It walks you through all the steps in setting up your OAuth for Twitter using Abraham Williams' TwitterOAuth. After that you can use everything that's described in the [API documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc).

Answer (score 1):

If your tweets are public, you can grab them in an rss feed without login.

Comment: That was my first try. The tweets are public, but still the RSS wants user/pass and fires "Simple auth is not supported any more". Strange...

Comment: [These are my tweets](https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/10217082.rss), you can access them without any form of authentication.